# mysql queries not working suddenly !

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I do simple select or insert it says-

> Unknown table engine InnoDB

It was working properly just few days back.what it's suddenly gone wrong ?

Comment: thanks guys for your response.I found out the problem was due selinux. mysql unable to  write into /tmp since tmp security context was changed. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons. Are you sure you've not changed anything (configs, updates?).

Check following:

1) Make sure you don't have skip-innodb in your mysql file.

2) InnoDB might be used via plugin, this may be your situation. Connect to mysql, execlute SHOW PLUGINS and SHOW ENGINES. This would give some info. You might need to install innodb plugin(s):

```
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_TRX SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_LOCKS SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_LOCK_WAITS SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_CMP SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_CMP_RESET SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_CMPMEM SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.so';
```

You might also need to reinstall/recompile plugins if they were deleted for some reason.

Comment: I checked with my friend- we made one change provided permission to a new user on newly created table.-Grant select, update, modify on DB.remap for efg; How does that turn-off/disable innodb?

Comment: What about output of 'SHOW PLUGINS' and 'SHOW ENGINES' commands?

Answer (score 3):

Check your MySQL error log. If there are InnoDB related errors, the InnoDB table engine gets disabled.